# rule on AWS WAF to block specific domain (URL)

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, block, amazon-waf

I want to know how to set a rule on AWS WAF to block a specific domain (URL) ... should I use host header in the rule? if yes how it goes?

I found something called Regex pattern set then I found that this feature is deprecated.

I want to block requests from specific domain (URL) from accessing my server.

Comment: You would need to block based on the HTTP Referer header (the name of website that linked to your site) not the HTTP Host header (the DNS name used to access your site). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referer